# F10 Key not sent to applications

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I'm running Ubuntu in VirtualBox (XP host) and while my F10 key works, no keypress events get sent to running programs. I checked in compiz and the shortcut manager, and found one thing using it, which I set to Ctrl+Alt+F10, but nothing else should be getting in the way.

I grabbed this program to be sure, and nothing happens when I press F10

```
#!/usr/bin/python 
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
prompt = ' Press any key '
label = Label(root, text=prompt, width=len(prompt+10), bg='yellow')
label.pack()

def key(event):
    if event.char == event.keysym:
        msg = 'Normal Key %r' % event.char
    elif len(event.char) == 1:
        msg = 'Punctuation Key %r (%r)' % (event.keysym, event.char)
    else:
        msg = 'Special Key %r' % event.keysym
    label.config(text=msg)

root.bind_all('<Key>', key)

root.mainloop()
```

When I press F10 in xev, I get

```
FocusOut event, serial 30, synthetic NO, window 0x5e00001,
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor

FocusIn event, serial 30, synthetic NO, window 0x5e00001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor

KeymapNotify event, serial 30, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Subsequent presses of F10 change the first 0 after 'keys:' to 2.

Is there any way I can get F10 to behave like a 'normal' F key?

Comment: Does this help? https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=43253

Comment: Haha, thanks for pointing that out. It's how I knew to look at compiz, but I missed the last line, "Note that the terminal emulator (console window) has its own setting: See Edit, keyboard shortcuts". Post that as an answer, and I'll accept it!

Comment: @Mehrdad NVM, realized that this isn't a problem with terminal (and unchecking the box doesn't even change that)

Comment: The NotifyGrab stuff suggests that you already have some application bound to F10.